# create-table with auto increment column?

Tags: sql, racket

Racket's sql module provides [create-table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/index.html?q=create-table#%28form._%28%28lib._sql%2Fmain..rkt%29._create-table%29%29) as abstraction for `CREATE TABLE` sql statement.

How should I provide specification of column (ie. id) with `AUTO INCREMENT` ?

When I try

```
(create-table numbers
  #:columns [n integer #:not-null #:auto-increment] [t text]
  #:constraints (primary-key n))
```

then it shows error:

```
create-table: unexpected term
  parsing context: 
    while parsing ColumnDef
    while parsing CreateTableInner in: #:auto-increment
```

Is it possible to specify auto increment column within [create-table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/index.html?q=create-table#%28form._%28%28lib._sql%2Fmain..rkt%29._create-table%29%29)?

Comment: I think I can live without auto increment, as far as I can live with sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `create-table` in the `sql` package doesn't handle `auto-increment`.
Instead consider using `query-exec` directly. Here is a snippet from Rosetta Code.

```
#lang at-exp racket

(require db)
(define postal (sqlite3-connect #:database "/tmp/postal.db" #:mode 'create))

(define (add! name street city state zip)
  (query-exec postal
    @~a{INSERT INTO addresses (name, street, city, state, zip)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}
    name street city state zip))

(unless (table-exists? postal "addresses")
  (query-exec postal
    @~a{CREATE TABLE addresses(
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          name   TEXT NOT NULL,
          street TEXT NOT NULL,
          city   TEXT NOT NULL,
          state  TEXT NOT NULL,
          zip    TEXT NOT NULL)}))
```

See more here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Table_creation/Postal_addresses#Racket

Comment: Perhaps @RyanCulpepper can say more?